# Finding maximum value from an array which contains positive integers and/or recursively nested arrays of positive integers

Tags: php, arrays, max

If an array initialized as:

```
   $arr = array(array(141,151,161),2,3,array(101,102,array(303,404,606,555,789,array(1000,22,9999,array(9057,100000),522))));
```

Then the result should be: 100000

I have written a function to solve this problem but I need less bytes and less memory of codes.

My Function is:

```
function MaxArray($arr){
$length = count($arr);
global $maxValue;
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        if(is_int($arr[$i])){

                if($maxValue < $arr[$i]){
                    $maxValue = $arr[$i];
                }

        }
        elseif(is_array($arr[$i])){     
                MaxArray($arr[$i]);
            }
        }
    return $maxValue;   
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Taken from PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php#109799) but authored by me:*

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 *
 * @return int|null Returns the largest value of the array. Returns NULL if no 
 *     integers are found.
 */
function array_max_recursive(array $array) {
    $max = NULL;
    $stack = array($array);

    do {
        $current = array_pop($stack );
        foreach ($current as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $stack[] = $value;
            } elseif (filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== FALSE) {
                // max(NULL, 0) returns NULL, so cast it
                $max = (int) max($max, $value);
            }
        }

    } while (!empty($stack));

    return $max;
}
```

---

- This function is not actually recursive, but fulfills the requirement that it works on sub-arrays. I enjoy doing things without the runtime stack from time to time.
- It returns something of type int, never a string representation of an int. The exception is when you provide an array that does not contain any integers.  It will then return NULL.
- It ignores non-array, non-int values.

Answer (score 4):

A handy function for walking over nested arrays is [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array-walk-recursive). It means that you don't have to worry about the handling the recursion yourself and can get on with the task at hand, in this case finding the maximum value.

```
function MaxArray($arr) {
    $max = FALSE;
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($current) use (&$max) {
        if ($max === FALSE) {
            $max = $current;
        } else {
            $max = max($current, $max);
        }
    });
    return $max;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the simplest answer. I like using `filter_var` more than `is_int`, but this is worthy of an upvote.